# Log all request and response headers in Gunicorn

Tags: logging, gunicorn

Is there a way to log all the request and response headers in gunicorn without knowing the header names in advance? From https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#access-log-format it looks like I need the specify the name of the headers that I want to see, but unfortunately for troubleshooting purpose I want to check if wrong or misspelled headers have been set.

Comment: I have the same question, any luck with yours?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing

Comment: same question here

Comment: Sorry guys, still nothing :/